# python no stdout from subprocess

Tags: python, windows, assembly, subprocess, stdin

I'm trying to pass a string to an exe and get its output. The exe just asks for a password then tells you if it's correct or not. Simple right? I've used subprocess many times before so im pretty confused as to why its not giving me the stdout here.

```
key="ABCDEFG\n"
process=subprocess.Popen(".\crackme1.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
outerr=process.communicate(key.encode())
print(outerr)
```

returns an empty stdout/stderr tuple `(b'', b'')`. any idea what i'm doing wrong here? I feel like i've got to be forgetting some simple thing but i've been messing with it for a solid hour now with no progress. in case it matters for some reason [this](https://crackmes.one/crackme/5c9126c033c5d46ecd37c8f4) is the exe and its usage looks like

```
Enter password:  WYVf3z8MF2
Password is correct! ;)
```

and the exact assembly used to read/write is

```
push    0               ; lpReserved
push    0               ; lpNumberOfCharsWritten
push    11h             ; nNumberOfCharsToWrite
push    offset aEnterPassword ; "Enter password: "
push    hConsoleOutput  ; hConsoleOutput
call    ds:WriteConsoleA
push    0               ; pInputControl
push    offset NumberOfCharsRead ; lpNumberOfCharsRead
push    64h ; 'd'       ; nNumberOfCharsToRead
push    offset unk_402010 ; lpBuffer
push    hConsoleInput   ; hConsoleInput
call    ds:ReadConsoleA
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the program reads from stdin rather than the terminal it is attached to? Some programs, such as the UNIX `sudo`, explicitly read the password from /dev/tty, not stdin. To interact with those programs you have to use a pty, which subprocess doesn't provide.

Comment: i updated the question to include the exact api calls. it does use ReadConsoleA though which i think reads from the console rather than stdin? thats starting to approach stuff i dont fully know. ill look into pty though and see if that fixes it!